# Google Sheets Conditional formatting to apply to both columns under merged cells

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Here's a sheet showing what I've got so far.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ihTTup_zDIeJNDAPSExGjrjnAe5QJ48plojrA43QtK0/edit#gid=0

Right now, the columns change color based on the value selected in the dropdown of cell two of the given column.  As you can see in my sheet, the first 4 (well, really 8) columns have merged cells across two columns in rows 2-7. What I'm hoping to achieve is to have the color change in, for example, cells B9:C55 if Cell B1 is changed.
I'm totally open to any approach on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom formula `=OR(B$2="A",A$2="A")` and `=OR(B$2="B",A$2="B")`

[image]